# proving a logical consequence when subtracting a tautology from a set

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

IfI have a set X of Well-formed formulae and a Formula P. I know that X ⊨ P.

If i am givin a tautology Q

then prove that X - {Q} ⊨ P

I don't understand why subtracting the set Q wouldn't make a difference to P being a logical consequence X.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We know that *Q* is a tautology already, right? So, for every valuation *v* that satisfies a set X, i.e. $v \vDash X$, then we see that $v \vDash X$ U $\top$. For this same reason, $\top$ is irrelevant when  contained in a set of assumptions: we can always subtract it preserving logical consequences.

Answer (score 2):

Let $v$ be a valuation that makes all formulas of $X\setminus \{Q\}$ true. Since $Q$ is a tautology, one gets $\forall \phi\in X(v(\phi)=1)$.

Answer (score 1):

Another way of proving it is by basic properties of the *tautological consequence* relation : $\vDash$

Let $\Sigma$ be a set of formulae and $\varphi, \psi$ formulae; then :

> - $\Sigma \cup \{ \varphi \} \vDash \psi \quad$ iff $\quad \Sigma \vDash (\varphi \rightarrow \psi)$ --- **(*)**

and :

> - if $\Sigma \vDash \varphi \quad$ and $\quad \Sigma \vDash (\varphi → \psi)$, then $\quad \Sigma \vDash \psi$ --- **(§)**.

---

Consider now $\Gamma \vDash \beta$, and let $\Gamma' = \Gamma \backslash \{ \alpha \}$.

If $\alpha$ is a *tautology*, we have that : $\vDash \alpha$, and thus $\Sigma \vDash \alpha$ for any set $\Sigma$ of formulae; in particular :

> *i)* $\quad \Gamma' \vDash \alpha$.

But $\Gamma \vDash \beta$ is $\Gamma' \cup \{ \alpha \} \vDash \beta$.

Thus, from **(*)** we have that :

> *ii)* $\quad \Gamma' \vDash (\alpha \rightarrow \beta)$.

Now apply **(§)** to i) and ii) to conclude with :

> > $\Gamma' \vDash \beta$.